# Redirect to another page when refreshing the page (F5)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a component to which the transition is carried out using a browsRouter. I need to, when the user tries to refresh the page, redirect him to the login page, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type). Place this in your component constructor :

```
if (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    // Redirect to login page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE **2022**

The next code is deprecated

```
window.performance.navigation.type
```

Now use getEntriesByType:

```
const entries = window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");

if (entries[0].type === "reload") {
    // Redirect to login page
}
```